# Do I need to edit scss or css to style my wordpress website?

Tags: css, wordpress, styles, sass, themes

I am using a wordpress theme and it has both **style.css** and **style.scss**. I want to make changes in the styling and I was wondering which file I need to edit? Both, **style.css** or **style.scss**?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Information Sass**

> CSS on its own can be fun, but stylesheets are getting larger, more
>   complex, and harder to maintain. This is where a preprocessor can
>   help. Sass lets you use features that don't exist in CSS yet like
>   variables, nesting, mixins, inheritance and other nifty goodies that
>   make writing CSS fun again.
>
> Once you start tinkering with Sass, it will take your preprocessed
>   Sass file and save it out as a normal CSS file that you can use in
>   your web site.

**Answer**
You need to edit the style.scss and then generate the style.css.
Once you started using sass oder less you'll never go back to css or regret it!
Learn how to Sass [**here**](http://sass-lang.com/guide).
An here is [**Software to generate**](http://sass-lang.com/install) the scss/less File.

Comment: Is it possible to just edit the style.css since I don't need the extra's in sass? So basically, sass has to be compiled into .css, right?

Comment: this is possible. but not recommended :)

Comment: if you ever generate the .css-File from the scss (which has in this case no changes bc you only changed the css) your changes will be lost.